# email not received javascript

Tags: javascript, html, smtp

I am facing problem in receiving email.

I have a registration form, when form is submitted email is kicked off, but I m not receiving the emails since last few days.

I have checked the folders under `C:\inetpub\mailroot` but i didnt get any badmail, drop folder. `STMP` server logs are saying it is successfully processed.

In the same application i have forgot password form, when the user clicks forgot password email will be send. this is working fine. i m able to get emails from forgot password. the only difference i could make is that in Registration form `mail.queue();` is used and in forgot password `mail.send()` is used. does this can be cause?

What else can be problem? 
Please help.

Comment: try sending your self an email

Comment: hi, i cant send mail. as this application exists in production. same application copy exists in QA region that works fine.

Comment: Can't you just try using mail.send() to see if it works? Also, what language are you using?

Comment: Yes i can try. the language is somewhat similar to javascript. client's scripting language. Mail.Send() will work. but we are using queue bcoz there is possibility that there can be bunch of mail send at a time.

Comment: will restarting the IIS can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally resolved this by re starting the IIS and SMTP Server. thanks to all for support.